# I know that rank (A+B)<= rank(A)+rank(B) but why is rank(A+B)>=rank(A)-rank(B)?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

> Why is $\operatorname{rank}(A+B)\ge \operatorname{rank}(A)-\operatorname{rank}(B)$?

It's obviously true if $rank(A)<rank(B)$ since rank(A+B) can't be negative but what if $rank(A)>rank(B)$?

Comment: How could rank be negative? In general, rank is defined as the dimension of the range space, that is the dimension of column space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can deduce it from the first fact:
$$\operatorname{rank}(A) \le \operatorname{rank}(A+B) + \operatorname{rank}(-B) = \operatorname{rank}(A+B) + \operatorname{rank}(B) \implies \\ \operatorname{rank}(A) - \operatorname{rank}(B) \le \operatorname{rank}(A+B).$$

Comment: Neat trick! Thank you for making this clear.

Comment: This is the first time I've used that trick for rank, but you see it for absolute values all the time, proving that $|a+b| \ge |a|-|b|$ from the triangle inequality.

Comment: +1: That's exactly the same realization I had for the first time (re: triangle inequality trick). :-)